# How to safely move and rename files based on REGEX into properly named directories

Tags: bash, filenames, cp, mv

In a large drive, I have multiple hundreds of files each named differently but with a few regular expressions. Each appended with random numbers and sometimes characters.

For example, there are 30 files named with a variation of the word "television", and another 50 varied from "lightbulb".

The thing is, that due to the bad coding practice I had years ago when implementing the script that generated the names, it's very inconsistent; so we might get:

- television139443.png
- elevision244904.png
- televisio097798.png
- elevisio984882.png
- _televisi90890890.png
- television-911181.png

You get the idea. That pattern applies to all the file "categories" --  "television", "lightbulb", "motorcar", etc. Luckily, there are at least 5 consistent characters in each filename which are not repeated in the other categories (a dozen cats).

What I'd like to achieve is to recursively go through the mixed folders, rename each file with the proper full title + appending creation date, and move them too their respective folder.

Sort of like:

```
   case : regex("levis"):
rename to Television-($creation_date).($extension)
mv to ~/Categories/Television/
break;
    case : regex("ghtbu"):
rename to Lightbulb-($creation_date).($extension)
mv to ~/Categories/Lightbulbs/
break;
```

Obviously this isn't proper code; it's just to illustrate the idea. I'm decently comfortable for everyday bash/zsh tasks but not fluent enough!

I would also need to gracefully handle cases where no regex is matched.

Comment: Are these *5 consistent characters* **always** the same? Like `levis` for `television`, `ghtbu` for `lightbulb`, etc.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't need to search for possible variations, i can easily make a list in which 99% of all files will match

Comment: Well, you can select each group using `find` then; and with an `-exec`, you can rename those files. This is either really trivial, or I'm missing a point

Comment: You can't have creation date. You can have the date that the file was last modified, though.

Comment: What should happen if you get two files with the same canonicalised name and date?

Comment: @roaima yes after 2nd thought the creation date isn't a good idea. + many of theses files are products of hardrive recovery and the associated metadata isn't reliable

Comment: Are the hundreds of files all in one directory, or are they in several? If in several, do you want/need to keep the structure?

Comment: @roaima there are few sub-directories but can easily select all file to bring them into one root folder. The intent(what im trying to achieve) is to "create the structure" based on the expressions. So one main folder with only one depth of subs

Comment: So what should happen if you get two files with the same canonicalised name and (modification) date?

Comment: Is the balance of the filename, the number before the extension, meaningful? Or just the product of the file recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could use a different approach based on its approximate matching feature:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmodload zsh/stat

dest=~/Categories
categories=(television lightbulb motorcar etc)
mkdir -p -- $dest/${(C)^categories}

zmv -n '(**/)(*[^0-9])<->(.*)' \
       '$dest/${c::=${${(CM)categories:#(#a3)$2}:-unknown}}/$c-$(
          zstat -F %FT%T%z +mtime -- $f)$3'
```

The `${(M)categories:#(#a3)$2}` looks for `$2` (the part before the number) in the `categories` array allowing up to three *errors* (different character, transposition, insertion, deletion).

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if OK.

For your approach, it could be something like:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmodload zsh/stat

dest=~/Categories
typeset -A categories

categories=(
  levis Television
  ghtbu Lightbulb
  otorc Motocar
)

mkdir -p -- $dest/$^categories

for k (${(k)categories}) (
  zmv -n "(**/)*$k*(.*)" '$dest/$categories[$k]/$categories[$k]-$(
          zstat -F %FT%T%z +mtime -- $f)$2'
)
```

Or if the *common* characters are always the 3<sup>rd</sup> to 7<sup>th</sup>:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmodload zsh/stat

dest=~/Categories

categories=(Television Lightbulb Motocar)

mkdir -p -- $dest/$^categories

for c ($categories) (
  zmv -n "(**/)*$c[3,7]*(.*)" '$dest/$c/$c-$(
          zstat -F %FT%T%z +mtime -- $f)$2'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort, can't seem to make it work, keep getting **zmv:239: no matches found: **/*$k*(.*)** - any clue where i could go wrong ? (ps: even tried with the same exat code you wrote and a bunch of dummy files), thanks, bonne année !

Comment: tried **setopt nonomatch** no luck

Comment: @I'maTIcalculator, sorry, my bad, it looks like I hadn't tested them at the time. There were a few issues. See edit, it should be better now.

Comment: thank you very much ! here's the final code i'm using if anyone is interested (just the zmv part, rest is standard) : 
`for c ($categories) (
 zmv -n "$dest/*$c[3,7]*(.*)" '$dest/$c/$c-${RANDOM}$1'
)`

crazy the amount of builtin functions zsh has ! also curious why the first part only works with double quotes "" and not single ?

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most efficient way but I would turn the problem on it's head and match the strings within the filenames to the directories and, since the current enumeration is random, just count them in to maintain uniqueness.

```
homedir=~/Categories
eval homedir=$homedir

cats="Television Lightbulb Bananas Motorcar"
declare -A count

for cat in $cats; do if [ ! -d $homedir/$cat ]; then mkdir -p $homedir/$cat; fi; done

while read f; do
    r=${f##*/}
    r=${r%.*}
    r=$(grep -Po "[a-z]+" <<<$r)
    for cat in $cats; do
        if [ $(grep -i "$r" <<< $cat) ]; then
            ((count[$cat]++))
            mv "$f" $homedir/$cat/$cat-$(printf "%03g" ${count[$cat]}).${f##*.}
        fi
    done
done <<< $(find ./banana/ -type f)
```

Non-matches will exit the `grep` loop silently and be left in place for special attention later on.

Anything else you want to include in the filename composition can go in, last modified date would be

```
$(stat -c %Y $f)
```

etc